# Can I use pop() function to pass a user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a homework problem and I wanted to improve on it a little. The idea is to allow a user to "pick an item to put into a backpack" given some options. I have that part down. What I wanted to do was use pop() function to remove the item chosen from the list once it has been "selected" via the user input. How do I get pop() to pass a random user input in the form of a string number 1-4?

I have tried setting the value inside the pop() to be the "input()" and the "itemToAdd" variable.

```
import sys

itemsForBackpack = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
itemsForBackpack = ["book", "computer", "keys", "travel mug"]


while True:
    print("Would you like to:")
    print("1. Add an item to the backpack?")
    print("2. Check if an item is in the backpack?")
    print("3. Quit")
    userChoice = input()

    if(userChoice == "1"):
        print("What item do you want to add to the backpack?" + " Select the number representing the item you wish from left to right eg '1 = book'."+ str(itemsForBackpack))
        itemToAdd = input()
        if itemToAdd == "1":
            print(str(itemsForBackpack[0]))
        elif itemToAdd == "2":
            print(str(itemsForBackpack[1]))
        elif itemToAdd == "3":
            print(str(itemsForBackpack[2]))
        elif itemToAdd == "4":
            print(str(itemsForBackpack[3]))
        return_value = itemsForBackpack.pop()
        print('return_value: ', return_value)
        print("Updated List: ", itemsForBackpack)
        break

    if(userChoice == "2"):
        print("What item do you want to check to see if it is in the backpack?")
        itemToCheck = input()
```

I think it wants an integer because I get an error saying that the string cant be displayed as an integer.

Comment: What does "a random user input" mean? If it's a user input it is not random

Comment: You might need to use `remove` other than `pop`

Comment: @DeepSpace: given the scenario, the program gives a message requesting input in the form of a string number. If a user selects "1" for the first prompt, then the user is asked to choose an item (corresponding to a number) the bag from the list. The input chosen by the user is not know ahead of time = random. I need the pop() to somehow recognize the input number chosen by the user to be converted into a recognizable integer and modify the list by removing the choice from the list. Long comment, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly, you could do it like this:

```
itemsForBackpack = ["book", "computer", "keys", "travel mug"]

itemToAdd = "2"

print('before:', itemsForBackpack)
print('removing: ', itemsForBackpack.pop(int(itemToAdd)-1))
print('after:', itemsForBackpack)
```

Output:

```
before: ['book', 'computer', 'keys', 'travel mug']
removing:  computer
after: ['book', 'keys', 'travel mug']
```

To remove a random item, you can use [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) to make the selection, and list's [`remove()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) method to get rid of it (instead of `pop()`):

```
import random

itemsForBackpack = ["book", "computer", "keys", "travel mug"]

randomItemToRemove = random.choice(itemsForBackpack)

print('before:', itemsForBackpack)
print('removing: ', randomItemToRemove)
itemsForBackpack.remove(randomItemToRemove)
print('after:', itemsForBackpack)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! That is part of what I was looking for. I was also trying to figure out how allow for the itemToAdd input to be random instead of predefined. How do I get the pop() to take the random input from the user to populate the open pop () brackets?

Comment: All this can be reduced to `itemsForBackpack.remove(random.choice(itemsForBackpack))`

Comment: @DeepSpace: Good point...although doing so isn't making use of `pop()` and there are other subtle differences, such as when the list contains duplicate items, although that's probably not important here — so I incorporated your suggestion into my answer. Thanks for pointing the shortcut out.